# how to add UIActivityIndicator programmatically in a custom view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using this library https://github.com/PiXeL16/RevealingSplashView to add something like splash screen.

I am using RevealingSplashView when fetching data from Internet,. but unfortunately if the request time is too long it will make the app like freezing. so I want to add something like UIActivityIndicatorView in the bottom center of the screen or somewhere else in RevealingSplashView.

```
var revealingSplashView = RevealingSplashView(iconImage: UIImage(named: "loadscreenLogo")!,iconInitialSize: CGSize(width: 110, height: 110), backgroundColor: AppColor.mainYellow.getUIColor())
revealingSplashView.addSubview(UIActivityIndicatorView())
```

but it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. You need an instance of UIActivityIndicatorView rather than using the class itself.

```
//loading indicator
let indicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView  (activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
```

Then load indicator - this is in the centre of the screen but we can easily change that with the .center CGPoint. You can make the indicator bigger with the .frame.

```
fileprivate func loading(){
    indicator.color = UIColor.gray
    indicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 15.0, height: 15.0)
    indicator.center =  CGPoint(x: revealingSplashView center.x, y: revealingSplashView.center.y - (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! )
    revealingSplashView.addSubview(indicator)
    indicator.bringSubview(toFront: self.view)
    indicator.startAnimating()
}
```

And when you are done

```
self.indicator.stopAnimating()
```

and remove the indicator